# Modifying non-dependency properties in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, because I'm new to XAML and WPF.

So this is an example of my question:

```xml
<ByteAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(Color.A)" Duration="0" To="255"/>
```

I want to modify the alpha of the background color like in the XAML line above. But it says that A is not a DependencyProperty. How can I modify Background.(Color.A) in the example above, or is it impossible to do? Please suggest.

Comment: You could use a [ColorAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Comment: I want to change only the Alpha channel of Color. Not R, G or B channels.

Comment: You can create an Attached `DependencyProperty` that will manipulate your Alpha Channel via code **or** you could maybe look into composing a few Borders in a way that you can use the `Opacity` property instead which is a `DependencyProperty`. The second approach might be easier as a newbie while the first one will teach you valuable lessons in the process. I will try to throw together a quick example.

Comment: Far easier: animate the Opacity of the Background Brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clemens' Answer has the effect you want. But you can also animate the Alpha-Channel by creating an AttachedProperty. Knowing this technique will also allow you to animate scrolling in a `ScrollViewer` etc.

```
namespace AlphaChannelAnimation
    {
    class AnimationProperties 
    {


        public static byte GetBackgroundAlpha(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (byte)obj.GetValue(BackgroundAlphaProperty);
        }

        public static void SetBackgroundAlpha(DependencyObject obj, byte value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(BackgroundAlphaProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BackgroundAlpha.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundAlphaProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BackgroundAlpha", typeof(byte), typeof(AnimationProperties), new PropertyMetadata((byte)255, OnBackgroundAlphaChanged));

        private static void OnBackgroundAlphaChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Color C = ((SolidColorBrush)((Border)d).Background).Color;
                ((Border)d).Background = new SolidColorBrush { Color = new Color() { R = C.R, G = C.G, B = C.B, A = (byte)e.NewValue } };
            } catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in your XAML:

...

```
xmlns:anim="clr-namespace:AlphaChannelAnimation"
```

...

```
        <Storyboard>
            <ByteAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="_BorderToAnimateAlpha"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(anim:AnimationProperties.BackgroundAlpha)"
                From="255"
                To="0"
                Duration="0:0:3" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: just to be clear: the outcome of this is **exactly** the same as Clemens' solution. But IMHO if you're serious about becoming a WPF developer, you should learn about and understand Dependency Properties rather sooner than later.

Comment: Where should I put the `xmlns:anim=""`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of animating the alpha value of a `Color`, you could simply animate the `Opacity` of a SolidColorBrush in the Border's Background:

```
<Border x:Name="Border">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Use a `DoubleAnimation` for the Opacity property:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
    To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

---

Full example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's the opacity of the whole background. Even with opacity 1 the color #00ffffff will still be invisible. +1 because I've just got an idea from this.

Comment: Sure, it's the Opacity of the SolidColorBrush. Don't confuse it with the Opacity of the Border element. If you had somehow animated the alpha channel of the Color, that would also be the opacity of the "whole background". The Color of the SolidColorBrush must of course be fully opaque, like #FFFFFFFF.